# Since symfony/framework-bundle 5.2: Accessing the "validator" service directly from the container is deprecated, use dependency injection instead

Tags: php, symfony

Estou rodando test unitário pelo phpunit e está retornando este warning no symfony.
**Since symfony/framework-bundle 5.2: Accessing the "validator" service directly from the container is deprecated, use dependency injection instead.**

Estou realizando uma injeção de dependência conforme o alerta sugere. Mas infelizmente continua retornando este warning.
Alguem tem alguma dica?

Trecho do código no test:

```
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $grupamentoRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(GrupamentoVariavel::class);
        $validator = self::getContainer()->get('validator');
        $this->grupamentoAction = new GrupamentoVariavelAction($grupamentoRepository, $validator);
    }
```

Trecho do código na classe:

```
 public function __construct(GrupamentoVariavelRepository $grupamentoRepository, ValidatorInterface $validator)
 {
        $this->grupamentoRepository = $grupamentoRepository;
        $this->validator = $validator;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você fez a injeção de dependência, mas ainda está usando o `validator` do container.

```php
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $grupamentoRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(GrupamentoVariavel::class);
        // $validator = self::getContainer()->get('validator');
        $validator = $this->validator;
        $this->grupamentoAction = new GrupamentoVariavelAction($grupamentoRepository, $validator);
    }
```

O mesmo poderia ser feito com o `GrupamentoVariavelRepository::class`.

Comment: Não é bem assim. A versão do symfony que estou utilizando não tem este $this->validator. Geralmente recupero pelo self::getContainer(). Mas por algum motivo tá retornando como depreciado.

Comment: O construtor que você postou não é o da classe onde está o método `setUp()`?

Comment: Lucas Não é de uma classe que vai ser testada é da classe GrupamentoVariavelAction

Comment: E você não pode adicionar esse construtor no seu teste?

Comment: Porque ? Outros trestes fazem o mesmo com outras classes e funciona. somente este que esta gerando warning quando injeto pelo container

Comment: Eu trabalho com Laravel, não sei como funcionam todos os detalhes do Symfony. Se quiser saber o porque disso é melhor consultar a documentação ou grupos focados no framework (por exemplo, no Discord).

Comment: Entendi. Manda um grupo de discord para que eu possa saber mais informações sobre o assunto. Pode ser ?

Comment: No site deles deve ter, realmente não sei de nenhum.